# pandas.read_sql_query passing in string parameters using an IN("A", "B") statement

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I have a list of string formatted like this:

```
string =  '"A", "B", "C"'
```

which I then transform into a set of placeholders using:

```
placeholders = ", ".join(["%s" for item in string.split(',')])
```

I'm trying to run the below query to pass in the string values as a parameter:

```
query = """
  SELECT
    XYZ
  FROM TABLE
  WHERE THING IN ({})
""".format(placeholders)


test = pd.read_sql_query(query, disk_engine, params=placeholders)
```

However this gives me an error, as the read_sql_query function is literally returning the "%s %s %s" string literally, rather than using the .format().

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: sqlite does not use `%s` for placeholders, try `?`

Comment: seems that you need `", ".join([item for item in string.split(',')])`